# Vulnerability : Communications.Unencrypted, Open communication detected in Java code

Tags: sonarqube, appscan

```
private DocumentBuilder getDocumentBuilder() throws ParserConfigurationException  {
        
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        
        factory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
        factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
        factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities",false);
    factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
        
        // Disallow external DTDs and Schema
        factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_DTD, "");
        factory.setAttribute(XMLConstants.ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA, "");
        
        return factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        
    }
```

I have scan my source code in AppScan.

This method
at this line's occurring vulnerabilities
**API**:-**Open communication detected in Java code

Classification:-Definitive

CWE:-311 - Failure to encrypt data

Vulnerability Type-:Communications.Unencrypted**

```
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities",false);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
```

what is the solution for this vulnerability.